Property 'ReactNode' does not exist on type 'typeof React'
I am using VSCode and tried this with apps made with both npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript and npm create vite@latest and followed the setup in the terminal choosing react and typescript. I already selected use Workspace typescript version in vs code.
I go to the app.tsx file in both apps and do
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

...

React.ReactNode;


The import of ReactNode is fine, no errors. However React.ReactNode; gives the error: Property 'ReactNode' does not exist on type 'typeof React'. And when typing React. intellisense suggests many things that are actually in the React namespace like Children, Fragment, useState, etc., but ReactNode is not one of them.
I tried making my project ts version match the ts version in @types/react as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55861272/10398996 but that didn't work.
I'm not sure what is going wrong and any help would be appreciated.

You can just use it as "ReactNode" instead of "React.ReactNode"

I know, but I still wonder why it behaves this way.
